# How can I read videos using See3CAM in Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have a camera called See3CAM_CU55M - 5MP Monochrome USB NIR Camera.

I want to read videos using Python and OpenCV. But the video and frames are not in a proper format.
Is there any idea how to read it in a proper way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from the company that I have bought the camera. I will share it here.

Thank you for purchasing our camera products, we received a query regarding the See3CAM_CU55M camera not streaming in OpenCV.

See3CAM_CU55M support for the Y8 and Y12 format. By default, OpenCV doesn’t support Y8 and Y12 formats. So, we have developed an OpenCV-based sample application – OpenCVCam, which is a command-line application for Streaming & Image capture along with the support for standard UVC controls of e-con System cameras in both Windows and Linux.

https://github.com/econsystems/opencv

Please refer to the installation manual to install the OpenCVCam application from the following link:

Windows:

https://github.com/econsystems/opencv/blob/master/Documents/OpenCV_Installation_Windows_Manual_v1.6.pdf

Linux:

https://github.com/econsystems/opencv/blob/master/Documents/OpenCV_Installation_Linux_Manual_v1.4.pdf